# Angular Share Cookies Between Subdomains

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies

I'm using tokens for auth and want to save them as cookies so it can be used between multiple subdomains.
I use `ngx-cookie-service` for managing cookies and cookies are only accessible on the subdomain they were saved on.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
  const token = await this.http.post(loginUrl, { username, password });

  this.cookieService.set("token", token, 1, "/", "*.localhost"); // doesn't work
  this.cookieService.set("token", token, 1, "/", "localhost"); // doesn't work
  this.cookieService.set("token", token, 1, "/", null); // doesn't work
  this.cookieService.set("token", token, 1, "/", "account.localhost"); // even this doesn't work
}
```

**How do I save cookies and use them on multiple subdomains?**